# Process evaluated too many times

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I have a simple design where I read incoming bytes from an RS-232 port and later "parse" them.

I tried to divide this into 2 processes:

1. first one receives bits from the serial port and tries to frame them - if it succeeds, it assigns the result to a signal named `next_byte` of type `unsigned(7 downto 0)`:

   ```
   -- simplified version
   rxbits := serial_rx & rxbits(...);
   if (rxbits contain a frame) then:
       next_byte <= ....;
       rxbits := (others => '1');
   end if;
   ```
2. second one has `next_byte` in its sensitivity list; it converts ascii `'0'`/`'1'` to bit values. I assumed it will be evaluated when `next_byte` is assigned:

   ```
   -- simplified version
   num <= num(...) & ascii_to_bit(next_byte);
   ```

It seems like process 2 is evaluated too many times when `next_byte` changes:

- If I send `'1'` to the FPGA, `num` immediately changes to all `'1'`s (I later show it on a seven segment * 4 display, so I can see that).
- If I send `'0'`, `num` immediately changes to all `'0'`s.

Why does it happen? What are the events causing it to be evaluated so many times? Maybe the fact it's not a "simple" signal (i.e not `std_logic`)?

By the way, running it in the ISim of Xilinx ISE doesn't reproduce those results - after sending a `'1'`, `num` updates as expected.

Also, if I remove the second process, and simply modify the first to be:

```
-- simplified version
-- next_byte is a variable this time
rxbits := serial_rx & rxbits(...);
if (rxbits contain a frame) then:
    next_byte := ....;
    num <= num(...) & ascii_to_bit(next_byte);
    rxbits := (others => '1');
end if;
```

Everything works *as expected*...

**EDIT:** I've modified the code a bit to *sum* the value of received digits (i.e `'1'` adds `1` to `num`, `'5'` adds `5`...). If I run it this using these 2 processes, the display (showing `num`) just flickers forever (-> process 2 is called *indefinitely*...); If I run it using 1 process, it works just fine.

**EDIT 2:** Minimal, yet reproduces the problem:

```
signal a: unsigned(7 downto 0) := (others => '0');
signal num: unsigned(13 downto 0) := (others => '0');

...

process1: process(clk)
    variable counter: unsigned(31 downto 0) := (others => '0');
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        counter := counter + 1;
        if counter(23 downto 0) = 0 then
            a <= counter(31 downto 24);
        end if;
    end if;
end process;

process2: process(a)
begin
    num <= num + a;
end process;
```

The display of `num` flickers forever.

But here:

```
signal num: unsigned(13 downto 0) := (others => '0');

...

process1: process(clk)
    variable counter: unsigned(31 downto 0) := (others => '0');
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        counter := counter + 1;
        if counter(23 downto 0) = 0 then
            num <= num + counter(31 downto 24);
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

It works just fine, the display of `num` increases as you'd expect.

Comment: Which RS-232 driver/jar have you used to read the port?

Comment: What do you mean? jar?

Comment: You've modified what code?  Without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), check your synthesis messages, baud clock rate, etc. How do you expect anyone to comment without seeing processes, declarations (type, subtype indication), and signal drivers? What is the return type of ascii_to_bit?  Why is next_byte unsigned? Synthesis effectively ignores sensitivity lists, if your code simulates but doesn't create working hardware, ...

Comment: Okay, added minimal source which reproduces this.

Comment: That's still not an mcve, it is enough even it we can't understand the bit about '0' and '1' as a value in an array type. Your `process2` is not (should not be) a synthesis supported sequential form, it's a gated oscillator (hence the flickering unless '0', it stops at `(others => '0')` ) caused by a combinatorial loop (and XST/etc, should have warned you). Notice that when you make it a true sequential assignment it works. Show us the synthesis warnings showing the combinatorial loop. Froob's answer is correct. Look for other warnings.

Comment: XST does spit out many warnings; as I said, I'm new to this whole VHDL thing so I didn't know what to look for in these - most of them are quite cumbersome... Thanks for pointing that out, I'll look more closely on them now :) The only warning I do understand there is `the following signal(s) form a combinatorial loop: num<12>.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you expect the sensitivity list to be observed after synthesis. The sensitivity list is strictly used for simulation.

Simplified, simulators work on the assumption that they only need to re-evaluate a process when some input changes. Back when VHDL was specified, computing power to compute which signals triggered a meaningful change in a process wasn't readily available. So the language creators resorted to telling the simulation tools on which signal changes to re-evaluate the process manually.

Your problem is that you're missing a signal in your sensitivity list: `num`

```
process2: process(a)
begin
    num <= num + a;
end process;
```

You expect this to only be evaluated when a changes. However, hardware doesn't work that way! In hardware, this is simply an adder with a positive feedback loop, so it will continue adding a all the time. To see the correct behavior in your testbench, add `num` to the sensitivity list, because if you look closely, you can see that `num` is also being read in your process.

```
process2: process(a, num)
begin
    num <= num + a;
end process;
```

You will now see the correct behavior in your simulation tool and likely get a message that you exceeded the maximum number of evaluations per step.

Think about it:

```
t = 0: num is 00, a is 00, num + a is also zero
t = 1: a changes to 01 due to your UART receiving '1'
       num is 000, a is 01, num + a = 001
       num is 001, a is 01, num + a = 002
       num is 002, a is 01, num + a = 003
       num is 003, a is 01, num + a = 004
       num is 004, a is 01, num + a = 005
       num is 005, a is 01, num + a = 006
       num is 006, a is 01, num + a = 007
       num is 007, a is 01, num + a = 008
       num is 008, a is 01, num + a = 009
       ...
       num is 255, a is 01, num + a = 000
       num is 000, a is 01, num + a = 001
       ...
t = 2: simulator will never reach this point in time
```

As you observed, the display flickers forever, because num is in a constant state of being incremented.

As you also found out, the solution to this is to make your adder synchronous. Add a `valid` signal that will only be asserted for one clock cycle to indicate a new character arrived from the UART. Only add `a` to `num` when `valid` is asserted.

But before change anything in your design, you should look at the output of your synthesis tool. Your synthesis tool will likely have indicated a) the wrong sensitivity list and b) a combinational loop in your design.

You'll have to learn to read the output of your synthesis tool and know which warnings are really just warnings and which warnings indicate a fatal flaw in your design.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer. So let me understand - a process like `process2`, in synthesis, is fully equivalent to a concurrent assignment `num <= num + a;` in an `architecture`? Is there any way to implement such kind of logic in 2 separate `process`es (i.e not use variables as the glue)? (I didn't exactly understand what you suggested to do with the `valid` signal)

Comment: You could make `process2` a conditional assignment based on a clock event just like you did in `process1`. FRob oversimplifies the characterization of VHDL simulators, delta cycles emulate concurrency. The 2008 standard also allows the keyword `all` as the only sensitivity list element automatically allowing the list to be generated (every signal evaluated in a condition or on the right hand side of an assignment).  Note you have a condition for updating `num` in `process1`  (`if counter(23 downto 0) = 0`) a valid indication.